# grouping multiple rows in to single row sql

Tags: sql-server

My log table has data as below

```
TransID  Name     Operation               Time
1       xyz       before update          2014-12-10 10:35:35.927
1       xyz1      after update           2014-12-10 10:35:35.943
2       abc       before update          2014-12-10 12:49:56.370
2       abc1      after update           2014-12-10 12:49:56.373
```

I need output something like below

```
Type     before update     after update          Time
Name    xyz               xyz1                   2014-12-10 10:35:35.927
Name    abc               abc1                   2014-12-10 12:49:56.370
```

Need help with the sql query.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

**BUILD SAMPLE DATA**

```
CREATE TABLE LogTable(
    TransID     INT,
    Name        VARCHAR(20),
    Operation   VARCHAR(20),
    [Time]      DATETIME
)
INSERT INTO LogTable VALUES
(1, 'xyz', 'before update', '2014-12-10 10:35:35.927'),
(1, 'xyz1', 'after update', '2014-12-10 10:35:35.943'),
(2, 'abc', 'before update', '2014-12-10 12:49:56.370'),
(2, 'abc1', 'after update', '2014-12-10 12:49:56.373')
```

## SOLUTION

```
SELECT
    t.*,
    l.Time
FROM (
    SELECT
        Type = 'Name',
        [Before Update] = MAX(CASE WHEN Operation = 'before update' THEN Name END),
        [After Update] = MAX(CASE WHEN Operation = 'after update' THEN Name END)
    FROM LogTable
    GROUP BY TRANSID
)t
JOIN LogTable l on t.[Before Update] = l.Name
```